# Passt das Verb »entlocken« in diesem Satz?

Tags: word-usage

> Es ist immer wieder verblüffend, welch tiefsinnige Erkenntnisse man dem Alltag entlocken kann.

Ist in diesem Satz das Wort »entlocken« richtig? Und welches Wort passt da besser?

Comment: Entlocken heisst in diesem Beispiel NICHT "etwas wegnehmen", sondern "herausfinden" oder "herausholen", umgangssprachlich auch "herauskitzeln". Insofern verstehe ich die Frage nicht... Der Satz ist absolut korrekt wie er ist, und entlocken ist das perfekte Verb an dieser Stelle....

Comment: Ich verstehe den Zusammenhang zwischen Titel der Frage und dem Text nicht. Zum Titel: ja. Zum Text: passt perfekt.

Comment: "Entlocken" heisst eigentlich nie "etwas wegnehmen", sondern "etwas heraufinden", "herausholen". Manchmal allerdings gegen den Willen des Beteiligten: "Der Kommissar entlockte ihm ein Geständnis".

Comment: @PMF Du hast Recht, ich war etwas voreilig. Ich hätte gedacht, dass man jemandem auch Geld entlocken kann. Dies steht aber so nicht im Duden.

Comment: @RoyPJ: ich würde im Zusammenhang mit Geld tendenziell eher nicht das Wort "entlocken" verwenden, mein Sprachgefühl sagt mir dass man das nur mit nicht-materiellen Dingen verwendet (Zusage, die Wahrheit, ein Geständnis). Kann mich da aber auch täuschen.

Comment: @0x6d64  Du täuscht dich  nicht. Niemandem entlockt jemandem Geld. Man entlockt im allgemeinen nur Informationen (oben im Gewande von Erkenntnissen).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Das Wort *»entlocken«* passt an dieser Stelle hervorragend. Mir fällt kein anderes Wort ein, das (bei gleichem Satzbau) besser passen würde. Wenn man die Aussage aber in einen anderen Satz packt, kann man natürlich auch andere Wörter verwenden, aber das halte ich nicht für notwendig. Der Satz aus der Frage ist stilistisch einwandfrei.
2. entlocken ≠ wegnehmen
   *jemandem etwas entlocken = etwas in Erfahrung bringen; etwas herausfinden.*
   Allerdings kommt weder in *»etwas in Erfahrung bringen«* noch in *»etwas herausfinden«* etwas vor, das die Rolle des *Jemand* einnimmt. Wenn man also auch aussagen will, von wem man etwas erfährt, muss man das noch irgendwie explizit hinzufügen.

Beispielsweise so:

> Es ist immer wieder verblüffend, welch tiefsinnige Erkenntnisse man *im Alltag in Erfahrung bringen kann.*
>   Es ist immer wieder verblüffend, welch tiefsinnige Erkenntnisse man *im Alltag herausfinden kann.*

Das ist aber schlechter Stil, denn Erkenntnisse werden, wenn man Wert auf guten Stil legt, nicht *herausgefunden*, sondern *gewonnen* (*»gewinnen«* nicht als Erfolg eines Glücksspiels, sondern so wie man Rohstoffe *gewinnt* wenn man Bergbau betreibt.)

Eine bessere Formulierung ist daher:

> Es ist immer wieder verblüffend, welch tiefsinnige Erkenntnisse man *im Alltag gewinnen kann.*

Diese Formulierung ist stilistisch gleich gut wie die ursprüngliche, an der, wie schon erwähnt, nichts auszusetzen ist:

> Es ist immer wieder verblüffend, welch tiefsinnige Erkenntnisse man *dem Alltag entlocken kann.*

---

Zur Frage in der Überschrift (die leider von der Frage im Korpus abweicht):

> Kann »entlocken« im Sinne von »jm. etwas wegnehmen« gebraucht werden?

Ja, aber so wird das Wort selten benutzt:

> Der Gauner hat mir meinen Ausweis entlockt.

Das bedeutet: Der Gauner hat mich durch irgendwelche Tricks dazu gebracht, ihm meinen Ausweis zu zeigen. Er ihn sich dann geschnappt und ist damit abgehaut.

Aber diese Verwendung ist selten, und aus meinem Beispielsatz geht nicht einmal eindeutig hervor, dass mir der Gauner den Ausweis tatsächlich weggenommen hat. Eigentlich sagt der Satz nur, dass mich der Gauner dazu gebracht hat, ihm meinen Ausweis auszuhändigen. Dass er ihn nicht mehr zurückgegeben hat, ist eine mögliche Schlussfolgerung, aber keine zwingende.

Comment: Ich finde deine Verwendung von "entlocken" im Sinne von "wegnehmen" (Beispiel Ausweis) nicht eigentlich richtig. Ja, es könnte schon sein, dass jemand, der sich sehr bemüht, kreativ zu sein, so etwas sagt, aber es klingt doch sehr bemüht.... so bemüht, dass ich es nach wie vor für nicht eigentlich verwendbar halte.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Ich gebe dir grundlegend recht. Es klingt sehr bemüht. Aber in der Frage ging es darum, ob diese Verwendung überhaupt möglich ist. Und da diese Möglichkeit besteht, ist die Frage mit *»ja«* zu beantworten. Mit allen Wenns und Abers, die alle durchaus berechtigt sind.

Comment: ... man kommt dann halt schnell auch dahin, zu sagen: Alles kann gesagt werden, unabhängig von Regeln und Traditionen, es kommt nur auf den Kontext an. Im Zweifelsfall ist der Kontext Kunst, und der Text ein dadaistisches Gedicht. Dann geht alles. Kann ich dir damit Zustimmung entlocken?

Answer (score 1):

Beispiele für aus dem Alltag gezogene Erkenntnisse:

> Was dich nicht umbringt, macht dich härter.
>
> Verlass dich auf andere, und du bist verlassen.

»Entlocken« impliziert Widerstand, man muss arbeiten, um etwas zu bekommen. Der vom Alltag geleistete Widerstand beim Herausgeben von Erkenntnissen besteht in der mehr oder weniger starken Kopfarbeit, die nötig ist, um eine Erkenntnis zu erlangen, man kriegt das ja nicht schriftlich. Die Verwendung von »entlocken« passt daher.

Ein besseres Wort als »entlocken« habe ich nicht, ist eine Erkenntnis allerdings so offensichtlich, dass sie so gut wie keine Kopfarbeit erfordert, lässt sich auch »entnehmen« verwenden.

Answer (score 1):

Ich finde das Verb *entlocken* an dieser Stelle nicht optimal, weil

- *Alltag* ein Abstraktum ist
- keine spezielle Aktion der Person auf den *Alltag* einwirkt

Daher finde ich besser:

> Es ist immer wieder verblüffend, welch tiefsinnige Erkenntnisse man (selbst) im Alltag gewinnen kann.